# Accessing children's of attached view to window manager

Tags: java, android, android-windowmanager

How do i access a webview within a layout attached to view to load a page.

I tried some possible ways which i thought could work including

```
void loadWeb() {
uiH.post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              LoadingWeb  = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
              LoadingWeb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
              LoadingWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
              LoadingWeb.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/page.html");
          }
      }); }
```

But is not working

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean android.os.Handler.post(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object
>   reference

How do i load a page to the bellow attached view

```
final IntentFilter theFilter = new IntentFilter();
theFilter.addAction(myDrawerReceiver);
this.myDrawingReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        try{
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            params.gravity = Gravity.FILL;
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) app.appContext.getSystemService(
                    Context.WINDOW_SERVICE
            );
            if(bundle.get("draw").equals("draw")){
                loadWeb();
                wm.addView(myWeb, params);
            }
            else if(bundle.get("draw").equals("undraw")){
                wm.removeView(myWeb);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(ussd.TAG,e.toString());
        }
    }
};
this.registerReceiver(this.myDrawingReceiver, theFilter);
```

webview **web** is in layout myWeb

Thanks

Comment: That `NullPointerException` is saying that the `Handler` is null, not the `WebView`. However, if the `WebView` is in a `View` that you've added directly with `WindowManager`, then calling `findViewById()` like that will return null, anyway. You'd need to call `findViewById()` on `myWeb`.

Comment: Can you give example? cos i tried something like `LoadingWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);` it gives NullPointerException on `onReceive(...)`

Comment: Am just new to Android

Comment: Assuming `myWeb` has been set by the time that `Runnable` executes, it would be `LoadingWeb = (WebView) myWeb.findViewById(R.id.web);`. That won't fix the `NullPointerException` you've shown above, though. That's saying that `uiH` is null, if that is indeed the code that's throwing the NPE. You forgot to assign that; e.g., with `uiH = new Handler();` I'm not sure how `onReceive()` figures into this, however.

Comment: Thanks sir; `LoadingWeb = (WebView) myWeb.findViewById(R.id.web);` solved the problem.